# Convert a date format from "Jun 25 2014" to 06/25/2014 Using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui

I have tried the following, but the output is not as expected.

```
title = "Jun 25 2014";
var n = new Date(title);
var dateformat = n.toLocaleDateString();
```

Comment: What is desired output?

Comment: http://codepen.io/leighquince/pen/gfexF - i get 6/25/2014, is this not what you expected?

Comment: helpful post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/where-can-i-find-documentation-on-formatting-a-date-in-javascript

Comment: Akhlesh - The desired op is 6/25/2014.

Comment: Quince- The o/p that i get is wednesday, jun 25, 2014. for the above code.But ultimately the o/p should be 6/25/2014. IDK why i am not getting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below code to get your output

```
var title = "Jun 25 2014";
var n = new Date(title);

if(n.getMonth()+1 < 10)
    var month = '0'+(n.getMonth()+1);
var date = month+'/'+n.getDate()+'/'+n.getFullYear();
alert(date);
```

Comment: The above code does work! Thanks..